Is there a way to change the block size of a disk partition without reformatting it?
I tried copying some browser cache files to a separate disk and although the free space was enough the disk run out of space because each small file used took up the minimum disk allocation space.
Is there a tool that change the block size without having to copying the files out, reformatting the disks then copying the files back?

What is the operating system, what are the filesystems of source and target?

@RomeoNinov OS is Debian, and both filesystems are ext4. The block size of the target is ext4

Check if the number of inodes is OK, maybe the problem is there: df -i /mount/point/of/other/fs

@RomeoNinov I meant the block size of the target is 4096. In fact I'm copying to a directory with the same partition. If the inode count is a factor I will check the inode count of the source directory and see if there are enough inodes to copy it to the target. Does every file require an inode even if they are 0 bytes in size?

You must check the inodes on target, you copy there. Yes, every file and directory need at least one inode. And please provide the command you use to get these 4096 bytes.

No, you cannot change a filesystem's block size value of a partition without reformatting the partition (i.e. creating a filesystem on the partition).
You can set the block size of an EXT4 partition via the -b option:
mkfs.ext4 -b 1024 /dev/sda1 

